# Single word for "at one's wits' end"

Tags: phrases, idioms, synonyms

While there often appears to be a word that could replace an idiom or a phrase in meaning, this one seems to be an exception (for me that is). I've tried:

1. Confused   : Less powerful, isn't it?
2. Dearth     : Needs completion by *of something*.
3. Vacuous    : Close, but complete absence of thought isn't the case, I suppose.
4. Speechless : Don't know if lack of ideas or happy, shocked etc.

I'm not sure if these words could be ignored because of the reasons I have mentioned, but you can clearly see that I'm at my wits' end on this one!

Answer (score 1):

Onelook suggested frazzled, which I think is rather fitting.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your intended meaning, *exasperated* could be a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

stumped, baffled, stupefied, defeated, beaten, blocked, confounded, exhausted, hopeless, desperate

Comment: ...  distrait, distraught, hysterical.

Answer (score 0):

Consider **[befuddled](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/befuddled)**

> confused, muddled, perplexed

Ohter possibilities are **bewildered** and the phrase **at sea**.

Finally, **[gobsmacked](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/gobsmacked)**.

Answer (score 0):

nonplussed, stymied, flabbergasted, aghast.